# Can I tell by looking at the files of a Rails app whether it uses a database or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a process where my git repository deploys to my live app when it is pushed from my local repository. I do this using a post-update hook (see below) to pull the changes to the live app.

```
echo "Pulling changes into Live..."
cd /var/www/$name || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master

exec git-update-server-info

# check if ruby app
if [ -f /var/www/$name/Gemfile ];
then
  echo "Ruby app detected..."
  bundle install --without development test
  bundle exec rake db:migrate # migrate database

  # check if database is used. If so, create database, database.yml, postgresql user and run db:setup
  # ...
fi
```

When it is pulling for the first time I want to setup the database if required. I assume this is what providers such as Heroku do, or if not they must setup a database for a new app on first push/ creation of project. But I don't know how to, from a bash script, to determine whether a application USES a database or not. I thought simply by detecting the presence of config/database.yml might be enough but perhaps this app doesn't use a database even though this file is present. Also, I won't include database.yml file in my commits so that file won't be pulled (or even pushed from local). If I check for the presence of files in /app/models/ would that be enough? or is there e.g. a setting in a config file that states whether the app uses a database? I only want to create a database when the post-update script detects that a database is used.

Comment: It is an unusual thing to do and I'm not sure there's a good answer, but you can probably check if they have ActiveRecord loaded. If they do, then they have a database whether they want it or not. If they don't then whatever database they're using, if any, is not going to work the way you expect. `rails runner 'begin ActiveRecord; puts "yes"; rescue; puts "no" end'`

Comment: I thought most hosts must have some automated process for setting up a database. I mention Heroku as when I create a new project there or when I make the initial push, a database is created too. I'm not sure if this is the place to ask for best practices but if there is a usual process for doing this I'd be keen to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look for database.yml or any model inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.

Answer (score 0):

**Buildpacks**

I don't know if you've done this already, but you may be able to glean information from [Heroku's buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

These are what Heroku use to determine which type of application you're using, and are open source (meaning you can find the [Ruby on Rails buildpack on Github](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) ;)

--

**Migration**

In terms of discovering whether an app uses a db, you'll be best looking at the `migrations` of the system. This won't be bullet-proof by any means, but will ensure the app has set up various database options to get it working properly

I don't have any code for this right now (can find some if you want, but it will be totally untested)

--

> I mention Heroku as when I create a new project there or when I make
>   the initial push, a database is created too

Interesting comment - Heroku only creates the database on its servers. There is a difference between creating a plain database instance, and populating with data. To my knowledge, Heroku does **not** populate your database with any data; meaning your question is really about trying to set up a "hardware-level" db for your app to use.

Comment: So Heroku's buildpacks can be run in my own production environment to deploy apps? I didn't know about these, thanks. I'll read more. Another project I came across was mislav/git-deploy which may work well for me too. It's been good learning the bare bones of deployment up until now but I think thereafter I'll use a more tried and tested approach (e.g. buildpacks, git-deploy).

Comment: The buildpacks are designed for Heroku's platform only - I recommended them because they basically work in the same way as you're suggesting -- using the `post-receive` hook in the `git` repo. Would you like me to find some code to loop through the `migration` files for you?

Comment: Actually I could possibly assume the presence of migrations would indicate that a database was required, right. Maybe for what I've got in mind would be sufficient but thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `db/migrate` folder and see if there are any migrations there.  This usually entails db tables.